# PyGTK Hide Cursor

Tags: python, linux, cursor, pygtk, hide

The question is simple how can I hide the cursor on an active window using PyGTK???

Here's a basic app I made to learn this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk

class app:

  def __init__(self):
    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    window.set_title("TestApp")
    window.set_default_size(400,200)
    pixmap = gtk.gdk.Pixmap(None, 1, 1, 1)
    color = gtk.gdk.Color()
    cursor = gtk.gdk.Cursor(pixmap, pixmap, color, color, 0, 0)
    window.set_cursor(cursor)
    window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)    
    window.show_all()

app()
gtk.main()
```

Obviously all it is, is just a window, however when I went to try and run it. I got this error.

AttributeError: 'gtk.Window' object has no attribute 'set_cursor'

After seeing that error I realized gt.Window won't be able to do it, but gtk.gdk.Window will. However how can I convert this basic window so it'll hide the cursor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [the PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq05.006.htp), you should set the cursor on the [`realize`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--realize) signal. If you don't wait for the [`realize`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--realize) signal, [the `gtk.gdk.window` hasn't been created yet](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--realize), so you can't change the cursor.

So, you can do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk

class app:

  def __init__(self):
    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    window.set_title("TestApp")
    window.set_default_size(400,200)
    window.connect("realize", self.realize_cb)
    window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)    
    window.show_all()

  def realize_cb(self, widget):
    pixmap = gtk.gdk.Pixmap(None, 1, 1, 1)
    color = gtk.gdk.Color()
    cursor = gtk.gdk.Cursor(pixmap, pixmap, color, color, 0, 0)
    widget.window.set_cursor(cursor)

app()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: I do same, but i see small dot. Debian 10, xord, openbox, lightdm. How to fix it?