# How to hide mouse curosr in an Python/Gtk+ application?

Tags: python, cursor, gtk, mouse

I'm writting a little application that runs on a touchscreen computer and I would like to hide the mouse cursor within this app. Do you know anyway to do that ?
Thanks

Comment: What about this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718586/pygtk-hide-cursor

Comment: this is base on pygtk which is not the same as Gtk+ but thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a GdkCursor of type GDK_BLANK_CURSOR, and set your windows GdkWindow cursor to that with [gdk_window_set_cursor()](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-cursor).

To get the GdkWindow, you need to wait until it exists (e.g. until the GtkWindow is realized), and then call `gtk_widget_get_window (my_gtk_window)`

How to do these calls with python depends on your Gtk+ version: 2.x indeed works through pygtk as barrios suggests (although the linked answer itself is incorrect). Gtk+ 3.x is accessed through gobject-introspection API.